# Python: how to drop columns if contain all negative values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
df
     A   B   C   D   E
0   -1  -3   0   5  -2
1    3  -2  -1  -4  -5
2    0  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

I want to drop the columns that contain all negative values and save them in a second dataframe. In this way I would like to have

```
df
     A   C   D   
0   -1   0   5  
1    3  -1  -4  
2    0  -3  -2  

df2 
     B   E
0   -3  -2
1   -2  -5
2   -4  -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) for less like `0` and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test all `True`s, then filter in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), here `:` means get all rows and columns by mask:

```
m = df.lt(0).all()

df1 = df.loc[:, ~m]
df2 = df.loc[:, m]
```

Or invert logic for test at least one `True`s by greater or equal value:

```
m = df.ge(0).any()

df1 = df.loc[:, m]
df2 = df.loc[:, ~m]
```